# Buffalo NAS access FILEIO

Tags: linux, lvm, raid, xfs, nas

Alright my Linux gurus, i have a situation. I am trying to recover data from a Buffalo NAS with 12 4 TB drives in RAID 6 totaling close to 40 TB on one array. It shows that the drive has around 36 TB of data stored. It appears that at one time it was configured to be iSCSI but has been lost. The Buffalo web admin area is extremely limited so I telnet into the NAS. I found the mount point but it is a file called FILEIO and can't access the contents. The mount points to /dev/md10 which is supposed to be for RAID 10 devices. It is an LVM using XFS, what is the trick to accessing FILEIO?

Comment: If it was used with iSCSI, the FILEIO file might be a disk image that was presented as an iSCSI LUN to the client system, and then partitioned and formatted to the client system's requirements. `file FILEIO` might tell more about it. If it has a recognizable partition table, then attaching it to a free loop device with `losetup` might be a good next step. If `losetup` supports the `-P` option, it can make things easier; but if not, `kpartx` can do much the same job if it's available.

Comment: `/dev/md10` has nothing to do with RAID 10!